# How to tar directories that do not contain files accessed the last day in shell scripting?

Tags: shell

How to find directories that do not contain files last accessed within 1 day and tar them under the shell?
i.e:

```
  ./
    directory1/
    directory2/directory3/directory/file3
    directory3/directory6/file5
```

if file3 has been accessed within 1 day then after the execution of the script i would like that:

```
./directory1.tgz
./directory3/directory6.tgz
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried hard to come up with a single big `find` command, but here is a little shell instead:

```
for i in ./*
do
    test -d "$i" || continue
    test -z "$(find "$i" -type f -atime -1)" || continue
    tar zcf "$i".tgz "$i"
done
```

Comment: I'd prefer something slightly different:
Now it tar"s" the root of the directory that does not contain this kind of files.I would like to tar the directory that contains the file that have not been accessed last day i.e:
`/directory3/directory6.tgz` and not `/directory3.tgz` . look at the question

Comment: I see. Now this gets really complicated (and messed up with archives). And it isn't well-defined for special cases, like "a directory containing only files not accessed in the last 24h, and also a child directory with the same properties". While surely feasible, I suggest you try and simplify your requirements.